# regex to get the text witnin the double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

What is regex to get the text within the double quotes.

My Regex is:

```
  "\"([^\"]*)\""
```

example: `"I need this"`

Output: `I need this`

I am getting: `"I need this"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following Regex you'll get what you want without any grouping

```
(?<=")[^"]+?(?=")
```

Code to get the the quoted text:

```
string txt = "hi my name is \"foo\"";
string quotedTxt = Regex.Match(txt, @"(?<="")[^""]+?(?="")").Value;
```

Comment: It helps but,i am getting the text after the quotes "" too....could u pls change it ...Thanks Example:-"it is all good"this is also comming....Output:-it is all good this is also coming..Thanks

Comment: @bhargava that's odd, i am not getting this

Comment: The problem is that the lookahead doesn't consume the ending quote.  The regex starts looking for the second match at the spot where the first match ended, and finds one almost immediately, because the lookbehind matches the same quote that the lookahead matched previously.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete solution to your problem:

```
string sample = "this is \"what I need\"";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"""(.+)"""); 
Match mat = reg.Match(sample);

string foundValue = "";
if(mat.Groups.Count > 1){
   foundValue = mat.Groups[1].Value;
}
Console.WriteLine(foundValue);
```

prints:

> what I need

Comment: This is the correct answer, but can you explain why it works (that they only want to print the group, not the entire match)?

Comment: The original regex works just as well and without having to resort to `.*` (or in this case `.+`). But +1 for pointing out that what's needed is `Groups[1]` instead of `Groups[0]`. I suspect that's the problem with the OP's program.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to post an answer?

```
string text = "some text \"I need this\"  \"and also this\" but not this";

List<string> matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"""(.+?)""").Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                       .ToList();
```